How do I call a global C function pointer in NASM without warnings?
Given main.c:
#include <stdio.h>

void (*fn_ptr)(void);

void foo(void);

void bar(void) {
    printf("bar\n");
}

int main(void) {
    fn_ptr = bar;
    foo();
}

and foo.s:
extern fn_ptr

global foo
foo:
    mov rax, fn_ptr
    call [rax]
    ret

we can run and compile it like so:
clear &&
nasm foo.s -f elf64 -O0 &&
clang main.c foo.o -z noexecstack &&
./a.out

which successfully prints bar, but also prints a warning:
/usr/bin/ld: foo.o: warning: relocation against `fn_ptr' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
bar

I couldn't find any online examples of calling global function pointers in NASM, and changing it to mov rax, fn_ptr wrt ..plt or call [fn_ptr wrt ..plt] prints this error:
foo.s:7: error: ELF format cannot produce non-PC-relative PLT references

(For anyone wondering what warning the -z noexecstack gets rid of):
/usr/bin/ld: warning: foo.o: missing .note.GNU-stack section implies executable stack
/usr/bin/ld: NOTE: This behaviour is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the linker


I'm pretty sure -fno-pie is not what you want.

@Joshua I don't know, but I do know I am not using that flag right now, and that foo.s in my actual program is a shared object

Well that settles that; -fno-pie won't work for you. I guess we both get to learn something real soon now.

From comments; I can now type answer.
The following assembly instructions don't work:
    mov rax, fn_ptr wrt ..plt
    call fn_ptr wrt ..plt
    call [fn_ptr wrt ..plt]

But these do:
    mov rax, [rel fn_ptr wrt ..plt]
    call [rel fn_ptr wrt ..plt]

The ELF format error is true. I'm surprised it can't handle mov rax, fn_ptr wrt ..plt but call [fn_ptr wrt ..plt] definitely cannot work. There's no such instruction as call [qword] but only call rel dword and call [rel dword].
The mov instruction that surprises me that it doesn't work wouldn't get you out of the problem anyway; that's asking for an absolute fixup in the text segment to refer to the plt by absolute address. So if it did work that's still a warning.
What you want to access functions elsewhere is always something with rel so you get a PIC-relative reference to the fixup area. Basic forms:
   lea rax, [rel fn_ptr wrt ..plt]  ; gets the absolute address of the address of fn_ptr
   mov rax, [rel fn_ptr wrt ..plt]  ; gets the absolute address of fn_ptr
   call [rel fn_ptr wrt ..plt]      ; calls fn_ptr


This is 64-bit code.  Indirect calls normally use 64-bit operand-size for the new RIP.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call shows call r/m32 is not encodable in 64-bit mode, only call r/m64.

@PeterCordes By call rel dword I mean E8 xx xx xx xx which does exist in 64 bit code (near call within same library)

Ok yes, that's call rel32.  But call [fn_ptr wrt ..plt] isn't an attempt at call rel64, it's call qword [mem] with an addressing mode that's either 32-bit absolute or (with rel) RIP-relative with 32-bit displacement.  So the right thing to say is that there's no [disp64] addressing mode, and like the error says, PLT-relative addressing modes must use RIP-relative addressing.

Also, the global variable is defined in a .c your linking (statically) into the same executable; you don't need to go through the PLT.  call qword [rel fn_ptr] works like normal for accessing static data in the same ELF shared-object (PIE executable).

@Joshua "so accessing a global variable in another library always takes two instructions" - I think I am encountering this now that I am trying to apply call [rel fn_ptr wrt ..plt] in my shared object, since it segfaults (the actual fn address was 0x55555556c840, but using mov rax, [rel fn_ptr wrt ..plt] I could see rax contained 0x56800001fc225ff). How should I do it in a shared object?

Nevermind, @PeterCordes their clue that I want to get the global variable from the .got (duh) got it working for the shared object case too! :)

Same as any other case of accessing static data from things you're linking into the same ELF object (PIE executable): directly with a RIP-relative addressing mode.
You don't need and don't want to go through the PLT unless you want to do symbol-interposition tricks with LD_PRELOAD with a library that defines a different global variable.  But I'm not sure that can do anything for an executable (not another shared library), and since this is a variable not a function, at most it could change the initial value to be something other than 0.
extern fn_ptr
default rel          ;;;; Added this

global foo
foo:
    call [fn_ptr]    ;;;; equivalent to call qword [rel fn_ptr]
    ret

I could also have done mov rbx, [fn_ptr] / call rbx / call rbx if I wanted to make multiple calls with the same function pointer without reloading the function pointer every time, also saving code-size.  Or lea rbx, [fn_ptr] / call [rbx] / call [rbx] if I wanted to just save a bit of code-size but still reload the function pointer for every call.

This is a variable so it doesn't have a PLT entry; those are for functions.  It will have a GOT entry if one is required, like if you were making a shared library and you want fn_ptr to be ELF visibility global instead of hidden.  (global is the default unless you use compiler options to change that.)
    mov rax, [rel fn_ptr wrt ..got]      ; load a pointer to the variable from the GOT
    call [rax]                           ; memory-indirect call, loading a new RIP from memory

This is similar to how you use GOT entries to call library functions the way gcc/clang -fno-plt does: Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code
If you don't need code outside your shared library to be able to read and modify this function pointer, make it __attribute__((hidden)) so you can access it directly with [rel fn_ptr], without the unnecessary level of indirection.

As Joshua's answer shows, you actually can use wrt ..plt, which makes an R_X86_64_PLT32 relocation instead of R_X86_64_PC32, but it does still resolve to addressing the global variable directly, not a GOT or PLT entry for it.  I don't know what PLT32 relocations are for.  There isn't a different machine instruction, it's still call qword [rel32] with a RIP-relative addressing mode, just I guess a different way of getting the linker to calculate the right offset from the end of this instruction to the global variable.  Maybe the distinction mattered for 32-bit code which didn't have RIP-relative addressing so would want to manually add an offset from the PLT instead of from itself.
   0:   ff 15 00 00 00 00       call   QWORD PTR [rip+0x0]        # 6 <foo+0x6> 2: R_X86_64_PC32        fn_ptr-0x4
   6:   ff 15 00 00 00 00       call   QWORD PTR [rip+0x0]        # c <foo+0xc> 8: R_X86_64_PLT32       fn_ptr-0x4

is disassembly from
    call [fn_ptr]                ; (with default rel so this is [rel fn_ptr]
    call [rel fn_ptr wrt ..plt]


Without default rel and/or a [rel in the addressing mode, see

32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?
How to load address of function or label into register - mov reg, imm64 with an absolute address needs a text-relocation in a PIE executable or shared object, hence the warning.

